# how to remove text added in a modal from an object after closing it

Tags: javascript, object, random, modal-dialog, dom-manipulation

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to add random jokes to a modal from an object. Until now everything works. What I want now is to clear the modal after I click the close button so that every time I click "lets have a laugh..." a new joke will appear without having to refresh the page.

Other suggestions to make the code cleaner are welcome.

```
const JokesObject = {
joke1: {
    question: "what is the ultimate paradox",
    answer: "There is no absolute truth"
},
joke2: {
    question: "what turns coffee into code",
    answer: "A programmer"
  }
};

function jokie () {

const ListJokes = Object.keys(JokesObject);
let randomJoke = ListJokes[Math.floor(Math.random() * ListJokes.length)];   
const joke = JokesObject[randomJoke];

const jokeModalQuestion = document.getElementById('joke');
const jokeModalAnswer = document.getElementById('answer');
const addJoke = document.createTextNode(joke.question);
const addAnswer = document.createTextNode(joke.answer);

jokeModalQuestion.appendChild(addJoke);

function answer () {
    jokeModalAnswer.appendChild(addAnswer);
 };

document.getElementById('giveAnswer').addEventListener('click', answer)
};

jokie();

const toggleModal = () => {
document.querySelector('.modal').classList.toggle('modal-hidden');
};

document.querySelector('.show-modal').addEventListener('click', toggleModal);

document.querySelector('.modal__close-bar').addEventListener('click', toggleModal);
```

Comment: `jokeModalQuestion.appendChild(addJoke);` should prob be `jokeModalQuestion.html(addJoke);` so you set a new object not append another. JokesObject should probably just be a list by default `[{question:...,answer: ...},{...}]`

Answer (score 0):

To make that possible, you need to move your `answer` function outside the main function (`jokie`), and whenever you open your modal, you set a variable with the answer the current joke contains.

That way, when the answer button is clicked, it will always be filled with the currently selected joke.

---

Here are some suggestions to improve the quality of your code.

*Please remember that beautiful code is subjective, some people might prefer a different way of doing things, but I think there's a general consensus about what "good" code looks like.*

#### Use an array instead of an object

You are using an object when what you want is actually an array.

Instead of

```
const colors = { color1: 'yellow', color2: 'red' };
const firstColorKey = Object.keys(colors)[0];
const firstColor = colors[firstColorKey];
```

Do this

```
const colors = [ 'yellow', 'red' ];
const firstColor = colors[0];
```

#### Use better namings

Don't try to be fun when naming methods / variables. Instead of `jokie`, use `setRandomJoke`. Try to be as verbose as possible.

#### Think of functions as units of work

Instead of having a single function doing all the work, try to separate work into different `units`. For instance, your `jokie` function was doing two things: getting a random joke and filling the modal with the joke text. That can be decomposed into two different functions: `getRandomJoke` and `fillJoke` (again, remember function names should be as descriptive as possible).

#### Use consistent naming

If you are using a rule for, say, class selectors, keep it consistent. You are using `giveAnswer`, which uses camelCase, when other class selectors are using hyphen-case.

#### Plase your constants values outside the function

You are calling `getElementById` to get the DOM elements all the time, when only once should suffice. You can achieve that by placing the constants outside your function.

#### Use a code beautifier

To stop thinking about indentation, people nowadays use a tool to automatically format the code. Prettier is heavily used among Javscript devs https://prettier.io/

#### Look into BEM for naming CSS classes

BEM (or alternative frameworks / methodologies) is used to keep a consistent naming on CSS code. In your code, you are already using some of that by using `__`, but you can improve that by instead of using `joke` and `answer` class names, using `modal__joke` and `modal__answer`.

---

#### Code

```js
const jokes = [
  {
    question: "what is the ultimate paradox",
    answer: "There is no absolute truth",
  },
  {
    question: "what turns coffee into code",
    answer: "A programmer",
  },
];

const jokeModalQuestion = document.getElementById("modal__joke");
const jokeModalAnswer = document.getElementById("modal__answer");
document.getElementById("answer").addEventListener("click", answer);
let currentAnswerTextNode;

function answer() {
  jokeModalAnswer.innerText = currentAnswerTextNode;
}

function getRandomJoke(jokeList) {
  return jokeList[Math.floor(Math.random() * jokeList.length)];
}

function fillJoke(joke) {
  currentAnswerTextNode = joke.answer;
  jokeModalQuestion.innerText = joke.question;
  jokeModalAnswer.innerText = "";
}

function showModal() {
  const joke = getRandomJoke(jokes);
  fillJoke(joke);
  document.querySelector(".modal").classList.remove("modal-hidden");
}

function hideModal() {
  document.querySelector(".modal").classList.add("modal-hidden");
}

document.querySelector(".show-modal").addEventListener("click", showModal);

document
  .querySelector(".modal__close-bar")
  .addEventListener("click", hideModal);
```

```css
.modal-hidden { 
  display: none
}
```

```html
<button class="show-modal">Show Modal</button>
<div class="modal modal-hidden">
  <button class="modal__close-bar">Close Modal</button>
  <div id="modal__joke"></div>
  <div id="modal__answer"></div>
  <button id="answer">Answer</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the extensive answer. I appreciate that. Will dig trough it tonight.